# Is this correct?- 'This Organisation is S.H.I.E.L.D..'

Tags: acronyms, periods

is this correct?

> 'This Organisation is S.H.I.E.L.D..'

Note the 2 dots that I put there after 'D'. What I meant was the first dot would indicate full form of 'D' & second dot the full stop.

Comment: Correctly written it will be: *This organization is S.H.I.E.L.D.*

Answer (score 12):

No, all the style guides I checked say to only use a single period:

> Q: If a sentence ends with an abbreviation followed by a period, should I insert another period to mark the end of the sentence?
>
> A: No. A sentence should never have two periods at the end. If a sentence ends with an abbreviation followed by a period, do not add an additional period:
>
> > She explained the rules for periods, commas, semicolons, etc.
>
> <sub>[Ask the MLA](https://style.mla.org/abbreviation-period-end-sentence/)</sub>

Comment: It is very unusual these days to see periods in the abbreviations of the names of organisations. Nobody now writes N.A.T.O. for the North Atlantic Treaty Organisation.

Comment: @JeremyC Yeah, most style guides recommend most acronyms be written without periods (see my answer [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/465161/191178)). However, S.H.E.I.L.D. is a fictional organization that is always written that way.

Comment: It's written that way about half the time. The other half it is written S.H.I.E.L.D.